# JQuery Isotope - Combination Filters

Tags: jquery, user-interface, filter, jquery-isotope

I could use some some help configuring the [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) gallery plugin!

I tried configuring the plugin with one filter only, and it worked perfect! BUT, now I am being courageous and trying to use two filters for the gallery, but I haven't been successful and the gallery doesn't work now. Although the code below looks overwhelming, I copied & pasted from the [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) doc site.

I have a feeling I am missing a setting or something... The settings from the doc site get complicated, especially when using a second filter. I am hoping that someone who has experience configuring the Isotope plugin can look at my code below (or view it on CodePen) and see where I went wrong...?

**JS:**

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope();

// store filter for each group
var filters = {};

$demo.on( 'click', '.button', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // get group key
  var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
  var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
  // set filter for group
  filters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
  // combine filters
  var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

// flatten object by concatting values
function concatValues( obj ) {
  var value = '';
  for ( var prop in obj ) {
    value += obj[ prop ];
  }
  return value;
}

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.ignite-thought' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.drive-results' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.focus-on-people' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.be-your-best-self' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.monday' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.tuesday' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.wednesday' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.thursday' });

// filter 
$grid.isotope({ filter: '.friday' });

// show all items
$grid.isotope({ filter: '*' });
```

View on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/KRyxBW).

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there. Two issues. One, is you didn't define your variable `$demo` and two, you have your filter click function targeting a class that does not exist for your button.

Define $demo:

```
 var $demo = $('.container';
```

Give your filter buttons the class your targeting:

```
       <div class="button-group" data-filter-group="color">
        <button class="button" data-filter="">any</button>
         <button class="button" data-filter=".monday">Monday</button>
         ...
```

Here is an updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/xjPQLR) ( I added a bit of CSS for the buttons)

Comment: Yikes, that's the consequence of copying & pasting from Isoptope site. Also, I was able to find the Isotope example with combination filters working perfect on CodePen: https://codepen.io/matie/pen/deZwGj

Comment: Definitely done that before! If this answered your question, please mark it as answered. Thanks!